# how to use set_id to rename node_id in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

this is my rename function, none of the options i've tried work, i do know, that set_id is the function to use but how?

```
 $('#jstree').on('rename_node.jstree', function (node,obj) {

    var node_id = "calculated"// calculate node_id
    // tried the following 3 options ..
   ....

     $('#jstree').jstree(true).set_id(obj,node_id); //not working

     obj.instance.set_id(this,node_id)// not working either
     obj.instance.set_id(obj,node_id)//nope..
```

So how do i set the node_id in jstree?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I looked at the API http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=rename&f=rename_node.jstree, and I think you have to use obj.node.

```
$('#jstree').jstree(true).set_id(obj.node,node_id);
```

`obj.text` should contain the new name of the node, and `obj.old` the old name of the node.

**EDIT**: The link to the API documentation does not match the code example.

Here are the correct links:

1. To set the ID of a node: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=set_id(obj,%20id)
2. To rename the node (set the text value): https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=rename_node(obj,%20val)

Comment: ah, i can't +2 sadly,

Comment: @wolfgang.  Agreed, still a great answer.

Comment: The API web link is: https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=set_id(obj,%20id).
Further, obj.text & obj.old do not apply to the coding example & is a result from the incorrect API web link.

Comment: @DrIanGregory Thank you for pointing that out. I added the links to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter you called `node` is actually the `event` object

Example creating a node then updating his autogenerated id

```
$('#jstree').on('create_node.jstree', function (e, obj) {
    #...
    $(this).jstree(true).set_id(obj.node, 42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following inside your on.() function:

```
 $(this).attr("id", node_id);
```

Comment: this changed the id of the div inside the drop down container, not the jstree node.

Answer (score 0):

Just set property id on the element you´re using to create the nodes.

```
<div id="jstree">
<ul>
    @foreach($feelings as $feeling)
        <li id="{{{$feeling->id}}}">{{{$feeling->name}}}
            <ul>
                @foreach($feeling->children as $feeling_children)
                    <li id="{{{$feeling_children->id}}}">{{{$feeling_children->name}}}
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($feeling_children->children as $feeling_children2)
                                <li id="{{{$feeling_children2->id}}}">{{{$feeling_children2->name}}}
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach($feeling_children2->children as $feeling_children3)
                                        <li id="{{{$feeling_children3->id}}}">{{{$feeling_children3->name}}}
                                            <ul>
                                                @foreach($feeling_children3->children as $feeling_children4)
                                                <li id="{{{$feeling_children4->id}}}"> {{{$feeling_children4->name}}}</li>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```